# Array of Structs in OpenMP in C

Tags: c, struct, openmp

I have very large code with Mulitple files, below is the snippet to only Show my issue. I am trying to run code on all processors independently (not conventional way of OpenMP , where some variables are shared).

please Forget about Header files. all necessary are included.

Main.c

```
static RT_MODEL_pl3phPWM_T pl3phPWM_M_;
RT_MODEL_pl3phPWM_T Array_m[4];
static RT_MODEL_pl3phPWM_T * const pl3phPWM_M_array[4] = { &Array_m[0], &Array_m[1], &Array_m[2], &Array_m[3] };

int main()
{
    int flag = 1;
    StartTime();   // in anotherfile
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    while(flag == 1)
    {
        rt_OneStep(pl3phPWM_M_array[k]);
        flag = EndTime();  //returns 2 when time > 15 seconds
    }

    return 0;
}


void rt_OneStep(RT_MODEL_pl3phPWM_T *const pl3phPWM_M)
{
    // here some other steps running OK. 

    pl3phPWM_M->Timing.t[0] = rtsiGetT(&pl3phPWM_M->solverInfo);  // Error Line, program stops working.
}
```

Step.h   // only the Struct part shown here, not complete file copied here. Header file is created correctly and working fine.

```
// Macro which is being used in error line 

#define rtsiSetTPtr(S,tp) ((S)->tPtr = (tp))
#define rtsiSetT(S,t)     ((*((S)->tPtr))[0] = (t))
#define rtsiGetT(S)       (*((S)->tPtr))[0]

// few other structs here  

struct RT_MODEL_pl3phPWM_T
{
    const char_T *errorStatus;
    RTWSolverInfo solverInfo;

    /*
     * Timing:
     * The following substructure contains information regarding
     * the timing information for the model.
     */
    struct
    {
        SimTimeStep simTimeStep;
        boolean_T stopRequestedFlag;
        time_T *t;                        // Problem when using this pointer;
        time_T tArray[5];
    } Timing;
};
```

Error line shown in Main.c works fine when compiled sequentially, but for parallel cores, it is stops working. I hope I have given enough info, but if something missing, please let me know.

Comment: Please apply proper formatting...

Comment: Adjusted formatting myself - please be aware that I allowed myself (as apparently not related to your actual problem) changing `int flag == 1;` to `int flag = 1;`, too.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks , I wrote super fast so made silly mistakes.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but instead of the additional pointer array you could simply have used `rt_OneStep(Array_m + k);`

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and read [ask] carefully. +"it is crashing" is a super vague error description.

Comment: @zulan further clearified. there is no error description, program simply stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is quite obvious: `pl3phPWM_M->Timing.t` is a pointer: `time_T* t;`

Nowhere in your code, you initialise this pointer, but as you use global objects, the entire structs get default initialised, which means the pointer is set to `NULL`.

By `pl3phPWM_M->Timing.t[0]` (or equivalent: `*pl3phPWM_M->Timing.t`), you dereference this null pointer, trying to assign something to it - thus the crash. I assume `rtsiGetT` returns a time_T struct (not a pointer to), so you could just remove the pointer in your struct: `time_T t;`. If you cannot do this for whatever reason, you need first assign it a value to:

```
if(!pl3phPWM_M->Timing.t)
{
    pl3phPWM_M->Timing.t = (time_T*) malloc(sizeof(time_T));
    if(!pl3phPWM_M->Timing.t)
    {
        // malloc failed! you need appropriate error handling!
    }
}
```

Now you *can* do your assignment as was. I would prefer to initialise the pointers right within the main function before entering the loop (you wouldn't need the outer if then - but still check the result of malloc!).